# How to determine what specific query causes high page reads/sec or page writes/sec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I determine what specific query/object in SQL Server causes high page read/sec or high page writes/sec?

Is there any specific dmv that I can use to help me with this problem?

Please help! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` DMV

For example this query gives you the top 5 most expensive queries you have

```
SELECT TOP 5 (total_logical_reads/execution_count) AS avg_logical_reads 
             ,(total_logical_writes/execution_count) AS avg_logical_writes 
             ,(total_physical_reads/execution_count) AS avg_phys_reads 
             ,execution_count 
             ,statement_start_offset AS stmt_start_offset 
             ,(SELECT SUBSTRING(text, statement_start_offset/2 + 1, 
                (CASE   WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),text)) * 2 
                    ELSE statement_end_offset 
                 END - statement_start_offset) / 2) 
               FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) AS query_text 
,plan_handle 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
ORDER BY (total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes) DESC
```

More information on [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/11/27/adventure-in-tsql-sql-server-query-performance-analysis-using-dmvs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL Profile. This link will help

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/

Comment: Hi I need a specific dmv or code because I'm trying to create my sql server monitoring tool using asp mvc! Thanks!